# Blocking WM_QUIT

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, pinvoke, message-queue

Quick question.

I have an app that use a native DLL through PInvoke, this DLL may call a PostQuitMessage().

How can I avoid it? (as my app should not close)

I tried AddMessageFilter, but it doesn't trigger the WM_QUIT.

Comment: I don't think you can because WM_QUIT never arrives at your window, it causes GetMessage/PeekMessage to return different values. Without the ability to change the message loop you are stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, IMessageFilter cannot work.  WM_QUIT makes the GetMessage() function return FALSE.  It never gets around to calling the message filter, the message loop immediately exits.  Overriding WndProc() or canceling OnFormClosing() won't work either.  The only workaround I can think of is [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to disable PostQuitMessage().  That requires some C/C++ skillz.

Comment: Same problem, the message loop exits before it can call DispatchMessage().

Answer (score 0):

PostQuitMessage() will have no effect if you call from a thread that doesn't own any windows.